# How can I query over all db of my server without looping over DB in pymssql connection

Tags: sql-server, python-2.7, pymssql

I'd like first to know how to make a query over all the databases in my server instance with pymssql (in MSSQL management studio = right click --> new query on the server thumbnail then don't need to specify the name of the db in the query - it just gives you one more column in the output which is the segment from which the record is from). Then how do you do the same as registered servers on two or multiple hosts (I have 2 hosts and I want to pass the same query do I really need to make the two connections ?)
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use sp_foreachdb, like this:

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE [?]; EXEC update table set foo = bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you (but - to be honest - I did not really understand what you want :-)  )

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```